# If we don't have free will, does that mean evil automatically exists?

Tags: free-will, determinism, problem-of-evil

If we don't have free will, can we be held responsible for our actions because they are deterministic? And if we can't be held responsible does that mean that evil exists?

Comment: Evil is a choice, if everything is determined there would be no evil. No good either.

Comment: Is it possible to held responsible for evil choices even if we don't have free willl?

Comment: How would the "holding" happen when everything is already predetermined, and where would the "choices" come from in the first place? Can game characters moved by a computer program on a monitor hold each other responsible?

Comment: So essentially, the theistic motivation for needing free will to exist is that if we don't have free will, God is responsible for the existence of evil?

Comment: If everything is determined God is not responsible for anything either, nor is there any evil to be responsible for.

Comment: The problem with this multiple choice homework question is that there isn't a multiple choice option for "there is no evil.".

Comment: This is a site for philosophy questions, not for doing HW. You'll have to guess on your own what your teacher had in mind from the class context. Or give an unexpected answer and defend it to him/her.

Comment: No free will, no evil, only negation. Any concept of "evil" supposes some sort of intentionality. But apportioning the responsibility depends on the theology, which might include not only one God but other fallen deities or beings capable of "evil" and of persuasion.

Comment: Of course we can be held responsible.  And those who hold us responsible MUST do so because they have no free will in the matter, either.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.

Comment: Please be aware that questions are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Questions, including those that are closed, can be edited to bring them within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Additional clarification at [the meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This question is way too broad. Start with narrowing it down and providing context.